# Reverse application usage of regex patterns

Tags: c++, c, regex

Is there a "ready way"/library to extract patterns for usage with `sprintf()` or `std::cout` from regex patterns?

For regex pattern validation I am using "regex.h"

And storing validating patterns as, for example:

```
"A((\\+|\\-)(\\d|\\.){6})\\r"
"G((\\+|\\-)(\\d|\\.){6})\\r"
```

I want to have something like `"A+%06f"`, `"G+%06f"`.

Comment: There isn't a way to do this, but for simple cases you can write your own. This answer is on [A+] regexes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28862668/2642059

Answer (score 0):

The `"regex.h"` that I am experienced with (some version of GNU libc) seemed to make many memory allocations when a regular expression was build on run-time, rendering it inefficient for simple patterns such as format specifiers, so I doubt any actual C library implementation would use regex.h for the format specifiers, which in turn makes it unlikely that a function such as the one you search for exist.

Also, your regular expressions seem to match strings such as `"A+......"`, which don't match neither of the format specifiers you gave.

Comment: No, it doesn't "seem to match strings such as "A+......"". And regex.h is POSIX, and not some version of GNU libc. And question was not about existence of such function in libc.

Comment: @Maquefel: `(\d|\.){6}` matches "......", [example](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28\d|\.%29{6}&input=......%201.2345).

Comment: @Zeta - yes. If the question is not clear i can clarify. Question is not about matches pattern something or not, it is about a ready library that can recognize (\\+|\\-)\\d{6} in pattern and replace for %+06d for example. If anyone is aware of existence of such lib, he will give information about it.