# Pass a string Recursively without Recreation

Tags: c++, string, recursion, construction, char-pointer

I answered a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28862668/2642059 Where I needed to use recurrence to step through a `string`. I wanted to use a `const string&` as my parameter on each function, but unless I wanted to reconstruct the string each recursion I found that I needed to pass a `start` and `finish` position as well as the `string` itself. So it became pointless to pass the `string` at all.

In the end I choose to just pass a `start` and `finish` pointer to the `char[]`.

---

As an example, say that I'm given a string which contains nested parenthesis (but no side by side parenthetical insertions.) So like this:

> (abc(def(ghi((j)klm)nop)qrs)tuv)wxyz

But not like this:

> (abc(def)(ghi)(j)(klm)(nop)(qrs)tuv)wxyz

I want to write a recursive program to extract the string in the deepest nested parentheses. Something like:

```
string foo(const string& bar){
    auto start = bar.find('(') + 1;

    return start == string::npos + 1 ? bar : foo(bar.substr(start, bar.find_last_of(')') - start));
}
```

However I'm unhappy reconstructing a `string` for each recurrence of `foo`. The alternative is to pass `start` and `finish` pointers as in the linked example (or to pass `string::const_iterator`s.)

Is there a wrapper or something which would allow me to use `string` functionality, but not reconstruct a `string`?

Comment: `std::experimantal::string_view` would probably help.  With some time travel you can even get it in `std` probably!  You could fake it, esp if you only need a subset of string functionality.

Comment: @Yakk I don't see that listed here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental Do you happen to know what TS that's part of?

Comment: I know it's just an example, but you don't need recursion to find the deepest nested parentheses. you can just search for the last '(' and the first ')' :)

Comment: @samgak I thought for a while trying to come up with a good way to showcase recursion on a string but couldn't come up with anything better. If you have something that would make a better example, please let me know. Obviously from my linked answer I wouldn't do recursion to find this, but rather I'd do this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28863236/2642059

Comment: [library fundamentals TS?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/experimental/string_view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view) from the library fundamentals TS might be one idea, support is available in GCC.

The interface is virtually identical to `string`

```
#include <experimental/string_view>
using std::experimental::string_view;

string_view foo(const string_view& bar){
    auto start = bar.find('(') + 1;

    return start == string_view::npos + 1 ? bar : foo(bar.substr(start, bar.find_last_of(')') - start));
}
```

The last line could also be

```
return start ? foo(bar.substr(start, bar.find_last_of(')') - start)) : bar;
```

Although they're both pretty cryptic.

Comment: I have to do `string::npos + 1` cause I did this above: `auto start = bar.find('(') + 1;` So if the `'('` wasn't found `start` will be:  `string::npos + 1`.

Comment: @JonathanMee I see, it kind of threw me off because using `npos` in arithmetic isn't something you see everyday.

Comment: `auto start = bar.find('('); if(start==string_view::npos)return bar;++start;auto mid = bar.substr(start, bar.find_last_of(')')-start); return foo(mid); }` is more sane, no?

Comment: @user657267 Yeah, [as mentioned by samgak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007753/pass-a-string-recursively-without-recreation?noredirect=1#comment46261315_29007753) this isn't a great example, I just couldn't think of anything simpler to showcase my question.

Comment: @user657267 I don't see support for this yet in Visual Studio 2015. I guess `const char*`s or `string::const_iterator`s are my options till the Fundamentals TS is accepted. (Fingers crossed for C++1z.)

Comment: I wish that I could accept both answers. When this is incorporated into the standard it will clearly be the go-to solution. It's really [Yakk's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29009821/2642059) that should be used until we have access to `string_view` though.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own `array_view<T>`.  It is a few dozen lines of code.

Use `std::find` to replace both algorithms.  In one case, use reverse iterators.  (or write a range-based find and range-based `backwards`)

Use `{T*,T*}` ctor to recurse.

```
array_view<const char> foo(array_view<const char> bar)
```

Here is a primitive `array_view<T>`:

```
template<class T>
struct array_view {
  using mutable_T = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;
  // 3 primitive functions:
  T* begin() const { return b; }
  T* end() const { return e; }
  array_view(T* s, T* f):b(s), e(f) {};
  // everything else based on them:
  size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
  array_view(T* s, size_t l):array_view(s,s+l) {}
  array_view():array_view(nullptr,  nullptr) {}
  // repeat next 3 for string, array, initializer list, C array as required:
  template<class A>
  array_view( std::vector<T,A>& v ):array_view(v.data(), v.size()) {}
  // may not compile for non-const T, but that is ok  you get an error:
  template<class A>
  array_view( std::vector<mutable_T,A>const & v ):array_view(v.data(), v.size()) {}
  // in a better world, you'd SFINAE remove the above from consideration
  // consider it for your next iteration of array_view.
  // conversion to containers:
  template<class A>
  explicit operator std::vector<mutable_T,A>() const {
    return convert_to< std::vector<mutable_T, A> >();
  }
  template<class C>
  C convert_to() const {
    C retval(begin(), end());
    return retval;
  }

  // utility functions:
  T& front() const { return *begin(); }
  T& back() const { return std::prev(*end()); }
  // Also rbegin, rend, and whatever else you find you are missing

  // inspired by std::experimental:
  void pop_front() { *this = {std::next(begin()), end()}; }
  void pop_back() { *this = {begin(), std::prev(end())}; }
  // but I find direct use of `view = {x,y}` almost as good
  // these kind of operations are the ONLY ones that are non-const
  // remember this is a view.  If you want a view of const data, make it
  // an array_view<const T>, not a const array_view<T>.  It really works
  // out better.
private:
  T* b
  T* e;
};
```

the above sample code is not tested.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your last statement: "Use `{T*,T*}` ctor to recurse." Isn't that going to construct a `string`, which this question was trying to do away with?

Comment: @jona no.  An `array_view` never owns, never copies.  It is a range view on `T*` with implicit ctors from vector, string, array, C arrays, and initializer_list, plus `T*,size_t` and `T*,T*`.  All it stores is two pointers.  It exposes range concepts: begin, end, data, size, empty, front, back, etc. (all `const`).  It is surprisingly useful and easy to write a usable one (if imperfect).  Have your code take and return array view on char.

Comment: Duh, thank you it makes more sense now. Yet, as you mention in your comment, I think `string_view` would be the first choice as soon as it's available, as this is effectively passing two pointers just as in my linked answer.

Comment: @JonathanMee `string_view` is also just two pointers.  All of the view dross is just to no longer have to manually mess with those pointers as directly, and to be able to view them as a single chunk of information.  I find once I had an `array_view` in my code base, half of the functions that used to take `vector` now took `array_view`, and it enabled really easy legacy code rewrites (with zero performance hit) to be container-based.  Give it a stab.  There are `std::experimental` stuff coming from Eric that is similar to the above (range views), I don't know if he has a contig range view.