# std::array as a parameter in virtual function

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I want to send `std::array` as a parameter to my virtual function

```
class Handler:
    {
    public:
        template <std::size_t N>
        virtual void handle(const std::array<char, N>& msg, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer>& buffers) = 0;
    };
```

but `gcc` said `templates may not be 'virtual'`. So how i pass a `std::array` to my function?

Comment: by fixing the size of the array (i.e. not having it as a template parameter). If you need variable sized arrays you can use vectors instead.

Comment: [use something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29009821/1774667).  Arrays are for storage, no need to store parameters.

Answer (score 5):

A member function template may not be virtual. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2354210/2069064).

However, you can make a virtual member function takes a `std::array` of *specific* size by moving the `N` out to the `Handler`:

```
template <size_t N>
class Handler:
{
public:
    virtual void handle(const std::array<char, N>& msg,
        std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer>& buffers) = 0;
};
```

Or simply passing a `vector<char>`, which given the context, could make more sense:

```
class Handler:
{
public:
    virtual void handle(const std::vector<char>& msg,
        std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer>& buffers) = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to make a member function template that accepts `std::array` and forwards it to your virtual member function in such a way that the size of the array is passed as a normal function argument rather than a non-type template argument. An illustration:

```
virtual void handle(const char* arr, std::size_t sz, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer>& buffers) = 0;

template <std::size_t sz>
void handle(const std::array<char, sz>& arr, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer>& buffers) {
  handle(sz ? &arr[0] : nullptr, sz, buffers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(simplistic) explanation:

1. A virtual function works because each class maintains a table of addresses of the virtual functions for that class.
2. A template function (or method) is not code, it's instructions on how to generate code.

so this:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void handle(const std::array<char, N>& msg, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer>& buffers)
{
   // stuff that looks like code
}
```

does not define a method. It tells the compiler how to write a different method (function) for each and any value of N.

in which case:

```
template <>
void handle(const std::array<char, 10>& msg, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer>& buffers)
```

and

```
template <>
void handle(const std::array<char, 20>& msg, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer>& buffers)
```

are actually different functions (that happen to behave similarly). Because they are different functions, they will occupy different addresses.

Therefore in order for them to be virtual, there must be 2 entries in the virtual function table.

This, for example, would work:

```
class Handler:
    {
    public:
        virtual void handle(const std::array<char, 10>& msg, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer>& buffers) = 0;

        virtual void handle(const std::array<char, 20>& msg, std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer>& buffers) = 0;

        // and so on for every value on N you need.
    };
```