# Passing multiple sized arrays to virtual method without using templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, dynamic

So I have a pure virtual class that needs to stay that way. In this class I have or technically need a method that takes in a templatized parameter. Here is the object type for the parameter:

```
template <int LENGTH>
struct MyStruct
{
  int arr[LENGTH];
};
```

And here is my method:

```
template <int LENGTH>
virtual bool send_struct(const MyStruct<LENGTH>& mystruct) = 0;
```

However, obviously I cannot use a template with a virtual class, the alternative being adding the template to the class, which I also cannot do for my purpose. Is there an alternative to this while keeping my constraints? I need to pass array of different sizes to this method inside my pure virtual class, but I cannot templatize the class.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "pure virtual class". There are pure virtual functions, and there are abstract classes.

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896202/stdarray-as-a-parameter-in-virtual-function

Comment: @PeteBecker I would describe a class that contains nothing but pure virtual functions as a pure virtual class.

Comment: @user2079303 You would?  I would call it an abstract class.  That is also the term used in the standard.

Comment: @user2079303 I'd call that an _interface_ ;-).

Comment: @NathanOliver A class is abstract if it contains any pure virtual functions. Therefore *pure virtual classes* are a subset of abstract classes.

Comment: Where's the dynamic array?

Comment: consider using [`gsl::span<int>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/gsl) instead of rolling your own.

Comment: How about passing `std::array` or `std::stack_array` ?

Comment: @SebTu That's basically having the same problem (`LENGTH`)

Comment: There's nothing dynamic in there. A dynamic array is e.g. std::vector.

Comment: I don't think (might be mistaken) what you want is not possible. However, if go up a level (what is the actual functionality you try to achieve / how do you want to use your interface) there might be a solution to your problem.

Comment: Can N be arbitrary or can it have only a handful of different values?

Comment: @Quentin I guess your right, edited title.

Comment: @MikeMB A handful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write this, as you know:

```
template <int LENGTH>
virtual bool send_struct(const MyStruct<LENGTH>& mystruct) = 0;
```

There is no way to pass through a *compile-time* `LENGTH`. But you can pass through a *run-time* length by *type-erasing* your container:

```
virtual bool send_struct(gsl::span<int const> ) = 0;
```

[`gsl::span<T>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/gsl/span) is a non-owning, contiguous container of `T`s. It's a view onto an array or a `vector` or whatever else, which can be a `MyStruct<N>` too. This type isn't directly constructible from your struct, but it's easy to write a version that is, or to add the necessary members to yours (`.data()` and `.size()`) to make it work.

An extremely simple implementation would just be:

```
class my_span {
private:
    int const* begin_;
    int const* end_;

public:
    template <int L>
    my_span(MyStruct<L> const& ms)
        : begin_(ms.arr)
        , end_(ms.arr + L)
    { }

    int const* begin() const { return begin_; }
    int const* end() const { return end_; }
    int const* data() const { return begin_; }
    size_t size() const { return end_ - begin_; }
};
```

And now you have a easily overridable `virtual` function for some non-modifiable container of `int`s.

Comment: would my function then be: `virtual bool send_struct(my_span &ms) = 0;` or something?

Comment: @arias_JC Not by reference, by value.

Comment: In your my_span class for `end_`, would it not be `end_(&ms.arr[L-1])` because as it is `my_span::end()` returns 0.

Comment: @arias_JC No it shouldn't be, that'd remove the last element from the range.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is in your `int const* end() const { return end_; }` function, what is it suppose to be returning. Because it has a pointer at the size of the array which would not be the last element but the one after, therefore always returning zero or technically null.

Comment: @arias_JC Yes, it returns a pointer to one past the end element. That's how ranges in C++ work. It does not always return zero - or really, ever return zero.

Answer (score 0):

Templates and virtual methods do not get along well. You will need to first isolate the templated portion of `MyStruct` from the rest of the class and only deal with the non-template portion with virtual methods. Second, you need to abstract the templated portion to provide a non-template interface that the virtual methods can use. For arrays, this is easy. You can simply provide a pointer and a size. To translate between the representations, add an intermediate non-virtual templated method which calls the actual non-template virtual method.

```
struct MyStruct 
{
    // All non-templated members
};

template <int LENGTH>
struct MyStructArray : public MyStruct
{
    // All templated members
    int arr[LENGTH];
};


struct OtherStruct
{
    virtual bool send_struct_impl(const MyStruct& mystruct, const int * arr, int length) = 0;

    template <int LENGTH>
    bool send_struct(const MyStructArray<LENGTH>& mystruct)
    {
        return send_struct_impl(mystruct, mystruct.arr, LENGTH);
    }
};
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind the overhead, you can store a pointer and size for `MyStructArray::arr` in `MyStruct`. This would allow you to use `arr` in every context where a non-template reference or pointer to `MyStruct` is used.

```
struct MyStruct 
{
protected:
    MyStruct(int * p_arr_ptr, int p_arr_length) :
        arr_ptr(p_arr_ptr), arr_length(p_arr_length) {}

public:
    int * arr_ptr;
    int arr_length;

    // All other members
};

template <int LENGTH>
struct MyStructArray : public MyStruct
{
    MyStructArray() : MyStruct(arr, LENGTH) {}
    int arr[LENGTH];
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make `MyStruct<int>` types inherit an empty base class:

```
struct BaseStruct {};

template <int LENGTH>
struct MyStruct : BaseStruct 
{
  int arr[LENGTH];
};
```

and define a virtual function which takes a `BaseStruct` and a `length`:

```
virtual bool send_struct(const BaseStruct& mystruct, int length) = 0;
```

Eventually, you could provide a convenient function to convert from those `BaseStruct` and `length` to a `MyStruct<length>`:

```
template <int LENGTH>
const MyStruct<LENGTH>& to_mystruct(const BaseStruct& mystruct)
{
    return static_cast<const MyStruct<LENGTH>&>(mystruct);
}
```

[Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b735a5fbde816d23)

Comment: How do you determine what `LENGTH` should be?

Comment: @NathanOliver Obviously, it needs to be known at compile time by the class implementing `send_struct`. See added demo.

Comment: No sure that that helps.  Since this is a member function, if they need to cast it back to the actual `MyStruct<>` then they can't get the size.

Comment: @Nathan I'd use something like a free function taking a good ole c-style opaque pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver It depends on what OP needs. But just to clarify, when you write "_Since this is a member function_", what function are you talking about?

Comment: `send_struct` is a member function.  I'm asking how it should convert the `MyBase` to the `MyStruct` when it does not know its size.  Hard coding the size into the class does not seem right since you just made the function able to take any `MyStruct`.  If your going to have a hard coded value in the class then whats the point of taking a `MyBase` when you could just hard code the `MyStruct`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Since a `MyStruct` size is known at compile-time, I'm guessing a class handling that kind of object may know, at compile-time, this size. If it does, my suggestion fix the "`send_struct` _needs to be a virtual function_" request from OP. If it does not, they might prefer a dynamically sized vector, don't they? Anyway, I'm not sure either this is the way; it's clearly _one_ way.

Comment: @YSC Looks good but my purpose is, when passing an array to that function, the array already has data. The derived classes implementing the method are not going to know the size, but the actual array passed in already contains all that information

Comment: @arias_JC If the derived classes implementing the method do not know the size then `MyStruct` is not fit for purpose. `MyStruct` by definition can only be used by functions that know (at compile time) the size.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Not if you have separate classes implementing `MyStruct` and them giving it its size. Then those class types can call to the derived classes implementing the method, therefore the derived classes do not need the size.

Comment: Guys, I understand the solution I suggested may not be the best in all situation, but with the question as it's stated, it's still is _a_ solution. Why the downvotes?