# How to read from the same location in a stringstream twice?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have an instance of `stringstream` that I am reading from.  At a certain point of getting data out of the stream, I need to read an identifier that may or may not be there. The logic is something like this:

```
std::string identifier;
sstr >> identifier;
if( identifier == "SomeKeyword" )
    //process the the rest of the string stream using method 1
else
   // back up to before we tried to read "identifier" and process the stream using method 2
```

How can I achieve the above logic?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Agreed.  Would deleting the second half of my question clear that up to focus on X?

Comment: Maybe if you describe what you're trying to do generally we can help you come up with an appropriate solution.

Comment: This has an easy enough solution that it may be the correct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the get pointer in the stream before you get the identifier and restore the position if the identifier is wrong:

```
std::string identifier;
std::stringstream::pos_type pos = sstr.tellg();
sstr >> identifier;
if( identifier == "SomeKeyword") {
    // process the the rest of the string stream using method 1
} else {
   sstr.clear();
   sstr.seekg(pos, sstr.beg);
   // process the stream using method 2
}
```

The [page on `tellg` at cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/) has a very nice example. The purpose of calling [`clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) is to ensure that `seekg` works even if the previous read reached end-of-file. This is only necessary for versions of C++ before C++ 11. If you are using C++11 or newer, `seekg` clears the EOF bit automatically and you should not include the line with `clear()` in your solution. Thanks to @metal for pointing this out.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Use `auto`.

Comment: @Deduplicator `auto` is only available since C++11. There is no guarantee that OP is using it and it really doesn't add much.

Comment: Well, it would have kept you from using a wrong type on first try, at least. That's enough to use it.

Comment: Note: As of C++11, `seekg()` clears the EOF bit before doing its thing, but pre-C++11, it inhibits the seek. So older platforms beware. There's also a potential efficiency problem in the "re-read" approach if the next item is a 10k character block of MIME data.

Comment: @metal Duly noted. The workaround would be to manually unset the bit before doing the seek, which I have edited into my answer. The OP is implying that his string will always contain data after the identifier, but of course you are right that percautions should be taken. I still prefer my answer and Remy's over Johnathan's because it applies to all istreams rather than just stringstreams. Generality at the cost of efficiency.

Answer (score 6):

Use the stream's [`tellg()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg) and [`seekg()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) methods, eg:

```
std::string identifier;
std::stringstream::pos_type pos = sstr.tellg();
sstr >> identifier;
if (identifier == "SomeKeyword")
{
    //process the rest of the string stream using method 1
}
else
{
    // back up to before we tried to read "identifier
    sstr.seekg(pos);
    // process the stream using method 2
}
```

Comment: This is almost a verbatim copy of my answer except the nifty link to `seekg`.

Comment: Your answer had not been posted yet when I was still writing and testing my answer. I saw yours after posting mine.  In my case, I thing using `pos_type` instead of `int` is more accurate, and using `beg` is redundant.

Comment: Fair enough. I fixed my type, although I think beg improves readability. Your links are better too.

Comment: Note: As of C++11, `seekg()` clears the EOF bit before doing its thing, but pre-C++11, it inhibits the seek. So older platforms beware. There's also a potential efficiency problem in the "re-read" approach if the next item is a 10k character block of MIME data.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly inspect a `stringstream`'s contents. That may be a clearer approach than extracting and rolling back, as you aren't guaranteed your `stringstream`s condition after extraction. For example, if your string only contained one word, extracting it would have set the `ios_base::iostate::eofbit` flag.

You could accomplish inspecting the `stringstream`'s contents like this:

```
if(sstr.str().compare(0, identifier.length(), identifier) == 0) {
    sstr.ignore(identifier.length());
    // process the the rest of the string stream using method 1
} else {
    // process the stream using method 2
}
```

One risk this takes on is, if you were depending upon the `stringstream`'s extraction operator to eliminate leading white-space you'll need to purge before doing the `compare`. This can be done by before your `if`-block with the command `sstr >> skipws;`.

While I do consider this method safer, it should be noted that if you are dependent upon leading white-space being in `sstr` for "method 2" then you should use one of the other answers (but you should also reconsider your use of `stringstream` since all the extraction operators first eat white-space.)

Comment: looks at user's score ... o.0

Comment: @pauld I answered this one question about how to display hearts in a game and voila!

Comment: This solution identifies a potential flaw in other answers with regard to EOF. (Note: `seekg()` clears the EOF bit before doing its thing, as of C++11, but pre-C++11, it inhibits the seek. There's also a potential efficiency problem in the "re-read" approach if the next item is a 10k character block of MIME data.) Nonetheless, I cannot endorse the conversion here of the *whole stream* to a `std::string` and then comparing part of it -- what if it's 100k of MIME data? That's an expensive conversion just for a compare. Also, this solution takes too much mental parsing for my liking.

Comment: @metal I'd like to say that the compiler will protect us from this, but that's not guaranteed. I'd also like to say that whenever [`string_view`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29007753/2642059) becomes a reality that this will be included. I was thinking at pulling directly from the buffer to avoid the incursion of the `string` creation, but it's hard to guarantee that the buffer has been filled :( Any better suggestions from you?

Comment: Instead of using `str().compare()` for peeking, you might try using `rdbuf()->sgetn()` instead to read `identifier.length()` number of characters into a local buffer without advancing the stream position, and then compare that buffer.

Comment: You are not allocating any memory for `prefix`.  You are passing an uninitialized pointer to `sgetn()` for it to write to. `prefix` needs to be at least `identifier.length()` characters in size. Per [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/sgetn): "*Reads count characters from the input sequence and **stores them into a character array** pointed to by s*".

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ugh, thanks wrong link. What I was actually trying to do was use a `char[]` for the first argument. Strangely everything goes haywire when I do this. I can do a `strcpy` into a `char[]` no problem, why should this be any different? http://ideone.com/ROrfxs

Comment: @RemyLebeau Finally got to an IDE and found the problem. It looks like `sgetn` doesn't add a trailing `'\0'` character. Which is... strange. Anyway, this fixes it: http://ideone.com/QKGQlY

Comment: @RemyLebeau Asked for clarification on why the string is not null terminated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135565/sgetn-doesnt-null-terminate-string