# sgetn Doesn't Null Terminate String

Tags: c++, buffer, stringstream, c-strings, null-terminated

[`sgetn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/sgetn) Takes a `char*` for it's first argument and writes characters to it. It does *not* write a trailing `'\0'` to the `char*`.

This behavior seems to be inconsistent with every other time that I can find a `char*` written to. However, it *is* consistent across Clang, gcc, and Visual Studio, so I can't believe it's a bug that all the compilers have.

Is there a reason that the standard doesn't require the trailing `'\0'` to the `char*`?

[[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c67b85506d33e75)]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it can be used to read arbitrary data, not just text.

Take e.g. the [`std::istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) function, it *also* takes a `char*` argument, but can be used to read arbitrary data, including binary data. You would not expect it to add a string terminator when reading from a binary file?

Comment: Wait, this is a `basic_streambuf`. [`fstream::rdbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/rdbuf) returns a `basic_filebuf` which I fully expect to need to be capable of reading binary data. What sense would it make to read binary data out of a `stringstream` (and correspondingly a `basic_streambuf`)?

Comment: @JonathanMee [`std::basic_streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) is the *base* class for all stream buffers classes. And nothing prevents a `std::string` to contain binary or arbitrary data.

Comment: I think your rationale is as good as I can hope for. But just because a `string` could contain binary data doesn't stop `data()` from appending a `'\0'`. This is probably just me being frustrated that it took me this long to identify the fact my `char*`s weren't being `'\0'` terminated. Thanks for the answer.