# Is a const string Still Preferable?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, algorithm, iterator

I asked a question on Iterators here: [Prefer Iterators Over Pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29099139/2642059) I've come to understand some of the protection and debug capabilities they offer as a result.

However, I believe that [`begin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/begin/) and [`end`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/end/) now offer similar possibilities on C-style array.

If I want to create a `const string` that will only be iterated over in STL algorithms, is there still an advantage to using a `const string`, or should I prefer `const char[]` with `begin` and `end`?

Comment: If you are using C++ you should prefer `std::string` over`char[]`

Comment: A quick clarification - from your view, is the additional std::string API (including the safer string::at(size_t) not that important?

Comment: `However, I believe that begin and end now offer similar possibilities on C-style array` - erm, the "iterators" there do **not** offer protection or debug capabilities

Comment: @NathanOliver the complication here is that even a `const std::string` cannot be constructed at compile time (yet) so the program **will** pay the price at start up/first seen when the string is constructed.

Comment: @Mgetz I thought C++ already had `std::string` literals.

Comment: @juanchopanza it does, but they are still runtime literals. They are still constructed at runtime. The user defined literal syntax is just a convenience. Without `constexpr` the construction must happen during execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer depends on what version of c++ you're using

## C++98

Because C++98 doesn't have [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) or [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) the best move is just to accept you're going to have to pay the costs of construction and use `std::string`. If you have boost available you should still consider [`boost::string_ref`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html) for two reasons. First its construction will always avoid allocation, and is overall much simpler than `std::string`.

`boost::string_ref` works because it only stores a pointer to the string and the length. Thus the overhead is minimal in all cases.

## c++11

Very similar to C++98 except the recommendation to use `boost::string_ref` becomes **MUCH** stronger because c++11 has `constexpr` which allows the compiler to bypass construction completely by constructing the object at compile time.

## c++1z

Allegedly (it's not final) the Library Fundamentals TS will be bringing us [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view). `boost::string_ref` was a prototype for an earlier proposal of `std::string_view` and is designed to bring the functionality to all versions of C++ in some form.

## On C++14 String Literals

C++14 introduced string literals with the syntax [`"foo"s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) unfortunately this is just a convenience. Because `operator""s` is not `constexpr` it cannot be evaluated at compile time and thus does not avoid the penalty that construction brings. So it can be used to make code nicer looking, but it doesn't provide any other benefit in this case.